# Does appending myjsfile.js?2342343 always force the browser to get the new .js file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Does appending myjsfile.js?2342343 always force the browser to get the new .js file?

Comment: only if the string appended is randomized.  What need would there be for this? I can understand an image that always changes, but why a *.js* file? Does it change that often?

Comment: @Jakub: it's the "cache forever" approach: you set expiration far in the future, and when the file changes, you change the querystring (e.g. to the file's last-modified time). With a new querystring, it will be a different resource, and browser will retrieve it - once (as it's again set to expire far in the future). Clever IMHO - it sidesteps the issues of conditional requests and certain browsers *cough cough* having problems with expiration times. IIRC there's a mechanism in RoR to do this automagically. See e.g. this: http://blog.httpwatch.com/2007/12/10/two-simple-rules-for-http-caching/

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the caching headers you send back with it. Without any `Cache-Control` or `Expires` headers, some browsers (e.g. IE) will treat the URL as always-stale, but this behavior is not guaranteed. On the other hand, if there are valid caching directives, browsers will respect them.

Comment: just when we change our .js file, i want the browser to pickup the new version (so we just change the #).

Comment: @Blankman: IIRC, RoR does this for you when you include the JS file through its methods. It's possible to do the exact same thing manually by checking the last-modified date and make that the querystring.